# Java SpringBoot apache-kafka cand deserialize an object

Tags: java, spring-boot, apache-kafka, spring-kafka

Issue with Kafka Producer and Consumer Configuration

I'm facing an issue with sending and receiving objects via Kafka in my Spring Boot application. I've configured a Kafka producer and consumer, but when I try to send an object using JSON serialization and then consume it, I encounter the following exception:

`org.apache.kafka.common.errors.RecordDeserializationException: Error deserializing key/value for partition exchange-service-2-0 at offset 1. If needed, please seek past the record to continue consumption.`

Kafka Producer Configuration:

```
@Configuration
public class KafkaProducerConfig {

    @Value(value = "${spring.kafka.bootstrap-servers}")
    private String bootstrapAddress;

    @Bean
    public ProducerFactory<String, Deposit> producerFactory() {
        Map<String, Object> configProps = new HashMap<>();


        configProps.put(ProducerConfig.BOOTSTRAP_SERVERS_CONFIG, bootstrapAddress);
        return new DefaultKafkaProducerFactory<>(configProps,
                new StringSerializer(),
                new JsonSerializer<Deposit>()
                        .noTypeInfo());
    }

    @Bean
    public KafkaTemplate<String, Deposit> kafkaTemplate() {
        return new KafkaTemplate<>(producerFactory());
    }
}
```

Kafka Consumer Configuration:

```
@EnableKafka
@Configuration
public class KafkaConsumerConfig {

    @Value(value = "${spring.kafka.bootstrap-servers}")
    private String bootstrapAddress;
    @Value(value = "${spring.kafka.consumer.group-id}")
    private String groupId;

    @Bean
    public ConsumerFactory<String, Deposit> consumerFactoryDeposit() {
        Map<String, Object> props = new HashMap<>();



        props.put(
                ConsumerConfig.BOOTSTRAP_SERVERS_CONFIG,
                bootstrapAddress);
        props.put(
                ConsumerConfig.GROUP_ID_CONFIG,
                groupId);
        return new DefaultKafkaConsumerFactory<>(props, new StringDeserializer(), new JsonDeserializer<>(Deposit.class).ignoreTypeHeaders());

    }

    @Bean
    public ConcurrentKafkaListenerContainerFactory<String, Deposit>
    kafkaListenerContainerFactoryDeposit() {

        ConcurrentKafkaListenerContainerFactory<String, Deposit> factory =
                new ConcurrentKafkaListenerContainerFactory<>();
        factory.setConsumerFactory(consumerFactoryDeposit());
        return factory;
    }

}
```

I suspect there might be an issue with the deserialization of the object when consuming it from Kafka. Any insights or suggestions on how to resolve this issue would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is a Class that contains full kafka configuration.

kafkaTransferDto is an object that send and receive to and from Kafka topic.
in your code KafkaTransferDto is equals to Deposit

```
import org.apache.kafka.clients.admin.NewTopic;
import org.apache.kafka.clients.consumer.ConsumerConfig;
import org.apache.kafka.clients.producer.ProducerConfig;
import org.apache.kafka.common.serialization.StringDeserializer;
import org.apache.kafka.common.serialization.StringSerializer;
import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Value;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Bean;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Configuration;
import org.springframework.kafka.annotation.EnableKafka;
import org.springframework.kafka.config.ConcurrentKafkaListenerContainerFactory;
import org.springframework.kafka.config.TopicBuilder;
import org.springframework.kafka.core.*;
import org.springframework.kafka.support.serializer.JsonDeserializer;
import org.springframework.kafka.support.serializer.JsonSerializer;
import sepah.neopay.base.dto.KafkaTransferDto;
import sepah.neopay.base.enumeration.PaymentType;

import java.util.HashMap;
import java.util.Map;

@Configuration
@EnableKafka
public class KafkaConfig {

    @Value(value = "${spring.kafka.bootstrap-servers}")
    private String bootstrapAddress;

    @Value(value = "${spring.kafka.consumer.group-id}")
    private String groupId;

    @Bean
    public ConcurrentKafkaListenerContainerFactory<String, KafkaTransferDto> kafkaListenerContainerFactory() {
        ConcurrentKafkaListenerContainerFactory<String, KafkaTransferDto> factory =
                new ConcurrentKafkaListenerContainerFactory<>();
        factory.setConsumerFactory(consumerFactory());
        return factory;
    }

    public ConsumerFactory<String, KafkaTransferDto> consumerFactory() {
        Map<String, Object> props = new HashMap<>();
        JsonDeserializer<KafkaTransferDto> deserializer = new JsonDeserializer<>(KafkaTransferDto.class, false);
        deserializer.addTrustedPackages("*");
        props.put(ConsumerConfig.BOOTSTRAP_SERVERS_CONFIG, bootstrapAddress);
        props.put(ConsumerConfig.GROUP_ID_CONFIG, groupId);

        return new DefaultKafkaConsumerFactory<>(props, new StringDeserializer(), deserializer);
    }

    @Bean
    public ProducerFactory<String, KafkaTransferDto> producerFactory() {
        Map<String, Object> configProps = new HashMap<>();
        configProps.put(ProducerConfig.BOOTSTRAP_SERVERS_CONFIG, bootstrapAddress);
        configProps.put(ProducerConfig.KEY_SERIALIZER_CLASS_CONFIG, StringSerializer.class);
        configProps.put(ProducerConfig.VALUE_SERIALIZER_CLASS_CONFIG, JsonSerializer.class);

        return new DefaultKafkaProducerFactory<>(configProps);
    }

    @Bean
    public KafkaTemplate<String, KafkaTransferDto> kafkaTemplate() {
        return new KafkaTemplate<>(producerFactory());
    }
}
```

KafkaTransferDto is a Class like bellow that name property is for source module name that have sent this object to the topic and object property is value of data that we want to transfer . object property could be anything like json,String ,etc

```
import lombok.Getter;
import lombok.Setter;

@Getter
@Setter
public class KafkaTransferDto {

    private Object object;
    private String name;

}
```

now we should create a producer class that sends KafkaTransferDto to the kafka topic like bellow

```
import lombok.RequiredArgsConstructor;
import org.springframework.kafka.core.KafkaTemplate;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Component;
import sepah.neopay.base.dto.KafkaTransferDto;

@Component
@RequiredArgsConstructor
public class Producer {

    private final KafkaTemplate<String, KafkaTransferDto> kafkaTemplate;

    public void sendMessage(String topic, KafkaTransferDto kafkaTransferDto) {
        kafkaTemplate.send(topic, kafkaTransferDto);
    }
}
```

Then we must create a Consumer class for consuming data from the topic

```
import org.apache.kafka.clients.consumer.ConsumerRecord;
import org.springframework.kafka.annotation.KafkaListener;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Service;
import org.slf4j.Logger;
import org.slf4j.LoggerFactory;

@Service
public class ConsumerService {


   private final Logger logger = LoggerFactory.getLogger(ConsumerService.class);

    @KafkaListener(topics = "MyTopic", containerFactory = "loggerKafkaListenerContainerFactory")
    public void consume(ConsumerRecord<String, KafkaTransferDto> kafka) {
       KafkaTransferDto dto = kafka.value()
       logger.info(dto);
       
    }
}
```

And finally we have a controller that sends kafkaTransferDto to the topic

```
import org.springframework.http.ResponseEntity;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.PostMapping;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestBody;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RestController;

@RestController
public class LogController {

    private final Producer producer;

    private final static String TOPIC="MYTOPIC";

    public LogController(Producer producer) {
        this.producer = producer;
    }

    @PostMapping(value = "/send-to-topic")
    public ResponseEntity<?> sendToTopic(@RequestBody KafkaTransferDto dto) {
        return ResponseEntity.ok(producer.sendMessage(TOPIC , dto));
    }

}
```